# How to connect Jira and Gerrit

Tags: jira, gerrit

I am using Gerrit and Jira. I want to connect with gerrit to Jira. When I review the code and comment something it will automatically update the jira comment as well. How to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `gerrit.config` file try this:

```
[commentlink "jira"]
match = ([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)
link = http://your.jirs_side.net/browse/$1
```

Here's [more information regarding the commentlink section](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#commentlink).

Comment: That just creates a link out of ticket mentions, it doesn't post back to the ticket, does it?

Comment: If you wanted to integrate with multiple jira instances, could you just have additional `commentlink "jira"` for the other jira links?

Answer (score 5):

Via [this link](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/?filter=plugins%252F) you will find a list of several official gerrit plugins such as:

- [hooks-jira](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/plugins/hooks-jira) : Plugin to integrate with Atlassian JIRA
- [its-jira](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/plugins/its-jira) : Plugin to integrate with Atlassian JIRA. New project for 'plugins/hooks-jira'.
- I personally use [jirret](https://github.com/hobbs/jirret), which is easy to understand and modify

Comment: I am new one. I don't know how to apply this. So can you please help me. I need how to integrate.

Comment: To install the official gerrit plugin, you just need to follow steps described here:https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-plugin-install.html

For jirret:
 - Drop hook files into $site_path/hooks 
 - Create JIRA user to post gerrit comments.  User should only need permissions to post new comments to issues
 - Setup config file in the home folder for the user that runs gerrit: ~/.jirretconfig

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a plugin to connect Jira and gerrit. You can download a plugin by using below link. 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.meetme.plugins.jira.gerrit-plugin